# Procreate for iPad Pro: How to multiply a (multi-layer) item many times in an efficient way?

Tags: ipad, procreate

I got the most recent version of procreate for iPad (2020), and I create an object with its one bundle of layers for texture and colours. However, I would like to make 100-200 or so copies of this item, and I was wondering if there is a better option than to duplicate it one by one many times over.

For instance, is there some way to 'spray-paint' a multi-layer object in procreate? I only seem to find instructors for how to do a simple duplication of multilayer items.

Comment: I haven't used the app extensively and I don't quite get the "multi-layer" part, but I'm pretty sure you can create a custom brush from a custom shape similar to how you can in Photoshop. I'm also pretty sure it has the same drawback, which is that it's single color only and the input is basically converted into a mask (for better of for worse). That said, at least in PS it's good enough for painting: https://youtu.be/SzWKvaTfjVI — Yea, it seems possible in Procreate too: https://youtu.be/U-d_opmtVoE ...If that is is even the kinda image spraying you were after.

Comment: Thanks, this is almost what I'm after, and I will look into this. However, a bit of the point is the 'multi-layer' part in my question. I don't just want to spray some simple shape around, I want to spray an object with texture and such things (multi-layer), the spray-paint function here only seems to work for an outline. This might however be one of the limitations in procreate.

Comment: I still don't get the multi-layer thing. Like technically when you brush, the image it sprays out is layered or... stacked, but it all happens inside one layer. Are you thinking it should also make a new layer for each sprayed shape? I wouldn't hold my breath waiting for that feature. — As for the limitations of the brush tool, it hasn't slowed artists down too much in PS... You just have to think about it a little differently. — The only application I've known to have a photo spraying tool is Paint Shop Pro. It doesn't seem to be a popular feature or at least it hasn't caught on in 20 years.

Comment: This is a question about procreate,... not photoshop (PS). And yes, I do make 'clipping masks' which is a form of sub-layers for each main layer. I might have up towards 5-6 sub-layers (clipping-masks) for each main layers to add texture, shadows, highlights and such. This is the standard way of working with procreate as far as understand.

Comment: My point was that PS has been around for a long time and artist's using PS have been able to live without like a "photo brush" and the brush seems to work just about the same as in Procreate. So that was just me saying, you'll do fine too if you manage your expectations and workflow to what is possible. For example, you could play with the brush opacity to add texture to the leaf brush. Or use multiple brushes like one brush for the shape of a rock and another for its texture. It's not ideal, but it is what it is.

Comment: So do you mean you'd basically like to take the contents of X number of layers and stamp those around the document while retaining the layer structure or perhaps making new set of layers. I don't know if Procreate has like a feedback forum or something. Might be worth a try. Then again I'm not really a procreate user and I could be totally wrong about all of this.